# Qual é a origem da palavra Senhor

Tags: significado, etimologia

Qual é a origem da palavra Senhor? Porque usamos como tratamento aos mais velhos ou para as pessoas importantes...

Answer (score 9):

Tem a origem na palavra *SENIOR* em latim.

> Ela deriva do Latim SENIOR, “mais velho, mais antigo”, comparativo de
>   SENEX, “velho, idoso”.

Fonte: [Origem Da Palavra - Site de Etimologia](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/pergunta/senhor/)

Foi primeiramente usado na idade média para determinar alguém com autoridade ou com proriedade sobre alguém ou algo: senhor feudal, senhor de escravos ou senhor de engenho. Também se referia a algo divino: Senhor. Inclusive o Rei deveria ser referenciado como Rey e Senhor.

> Os primeiros textos portugueses, segundo Marilina dos Santos Luz,
>   “recebem o termo senhor como o significado de ‘pessoa que tem
>   autoridade e direitos sobre alguém ou alguma coisa’”, ainda na Idade
>   Média. Temos inúmeros exemplos desse uso ao longo das histórias
>   portuguesa e brasileira, como senhor das terras (senhor feudal),
>   senhor de escravos, senhor de engenho. Historicamente também, o termo
>   se aplicou aos reis, que, depois de Deus, era aquele a quem melhor se
>   adaptava o nome de senhor. Nesse sentido, ao aproximar o pronome de
>   tratamento ao termo bíblico Senhor, estabelecia-se uma origem divina
>   do rei. Ao referir-se a um rei, os súditos não se esqueciam que ele
>   era Rey e Senhor. Durante um certo período este foi o tratamento mais
>   apreciado pelos reis e considerado mais conveniente pelas pessoas que
>   dele se aproximavam. O termo também era usado para os representantes
>   das mais elevadas classes sociais, substituindo, por vezes, outros
>   títulos de nobreza; era freqüente os condes serem tratados
>   singelamente por senhor. Posteriormente, senhor adquire a
>   possibilidade de ser usado como prenome, com uma nova função,
>   designando ainda autoridade, mas também respeito.

Após isso, também foi utilizado quando havia diferenças sociais.

> Já na Idade Média e, posteriormente, no século XV, o termo era usado
>   de superior para inferior, para demonstrar a diferença social,
>   verificada por exemplo, quando D. João incita seus soldados: “Avamte,
>   senhores! Avamte, avamte” (F. Lopes, Crón. D. João, p. 107).

Nos anos 80, começando a ser utilizado como forma de respeito para pessoas mais velhas ou para manter um distânciamento social.

> Mudando radicalmente de época, nos anos 80 e, principalmente, nos anos
>   90 deste século, o pronome de tratamento senhor(a) adquire novos usos,
>   restringe-se a outras situações, bem distintas das já vistas.
>   Atualmente, seu uso é muito mais regido pela idade e pela distância
>   social que pela autoridade, mas conserva ainda arraigado alguns
>   valores que remontam à época dos reis e senhores como submissão e 
>   respeito (aos “superiores”).

Atualmente, é utilizado como forma de ser mais cortês ou amável. E pode ser mal interpretado, achando que a pessoas que estamos falando é bem mais velha.

> Notamos que, hoje em dia, o uso de você é extremamente disseminado.
>   Deixou o campo familiar e íntimo para ser usado entre iguais, de
>   superior para inferior e de inferior para superior, dependendo da
>   ocasião. Tal uso pode ser uma forma de ser cortês ou amável, de tentar
>   uma proximidade ou um galanteio. O termo senhor, muitas vezes, é
>   considerado pejorativo, indicando, supostamente, ou que a pessoa com
>   quem falamos é bem mais velha (o que não é educado, segundo a
>   “etiqueta”) ou uma frieza, uma distância entre as pessoas

Por fim, nota-se que está entrando em desuso e dependendo da utilização até ser desrespeitoso.

> Ironicamente, um pronome originariamente usado para referir-se a reis,
>   aproximando-os do Senhor –  portanto, muito nobre –, hoje é
>   considerado ultrapassado, pejorativo, em certa medida até
>   desrespeitoso. O valor bíblico associado ao termo ainda é muito
>   presente e muitas pessoas, quando tratadas por senhor ou senhora,
>   respondem de imediato: “O Senhor (A Senhora) está no Céu”.

Fonte: [Discussões Sobre a Alternância Você e o Senhor, a Senhora](http://www.unicamp.br/iel/site/alunos/publicacoes/textos/a00002.htm)

Comment: ..Bom trabalho.

Comment: Agradecido pelo reconhecimento!

Comment: "nota-se que está entrando em desuso e dependendo da utilização até ser desrespeitoso" Porque você não falou em "O senhor Teixeira", uso formal?.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com algumas pesquisas e estudos, a palavra senhor vem do Latim seniōris, senĭor, e significa “mais velho, mais antigo”, e é o comparativo de senis, senex, quer dizer “velho, ancião”.
Observa-se que a terminação -or é comum para os comparativos e permaneceu no Português do Brasil e outros em palavras como “pior” [do lat. peior, peius] e “melhor” [do lat. melior, melius].
Assim, fica claro que se o uso não tivesse transformado essa palavra em substantivo, talvez hoje disséssemos algo como “Você é senhor do que eu” para dizer “Você é mais velho do que eu”. No entanto, isso é apenas um exercício imaginativo. Como comparativo, o senhor morreu. Vida longa ao senhor.
A palavra senhor também é usada em muitos outros contextos, tais como: 
Proprietário, dono absoluto, possuidor de algum Estado, território ou objeto.[História] Aquele que tinha autoridade feudal sobre certas pessoas ou propriedades; proprietário feudal. Pessoa nobre, de alta consideração.

[Gramática] Forma de tratamento cerimoniosa entre pessoas que não têm intimidade e não se tratam por você.  Soberano, chefe; título honorífico de alguns monarcas.

[Figurado] Quem domina algo, alguém ou si mesmo: senhor de si.Dono de casa; proprietário: nenhum senhor manda aqui.Pessoa distinta: senhor da sociedade.

[Antigo] Título conferido a pessoas distintas, por posição ou dignidade de que estavam investidas.[Antigo] Título de nobreza de alguns fidalgos.

[Antigo] O marido em relação à esposa.adjetivoSugere a ideia de grande, perfeito, admirável: ele tem um senhor automóvel!Etimologia (origem da palavra senhor). Do latim senior.onis.
[Gramática] Forma abreviada: Sr.
Sinônimos de Senhor
Senhor é sinônimo de: amo, senhoril
Se quiser saber mais
[image]
[image]
[enter link description here](http://biblia.com.br/dicionario-biblico/s/senhor/)
[enter link description here](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/senhor/)
[enter link description here](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/senhor)

[enter link description here](https://www.dicio.com.br/senhor/)